# Accessing TcpClient in VB.net DLL

Tags: vb.net, tcpclient

I'm writing a DLL for [SimTools](https://www.xsimulator.net/community/marketplace/motion-simulation-software-simtools.63/) that accesses the telemetry data of [NoLimitsRollercoasterSimulator](http://www.nolimitscoaster.com/). The TcpClient is created during loading the DLL with

```
Dim tcpClientNLS As New TcpClient()
```

The `tcpClientNLS` can then be accessed by all the different subroutines in the DLL. When I create the TcpClient in one of the subroutines (e.g. `Public Sub GameStart()` ) the client is only accessible in this subroutine (`GameStart`). The issues is that when the NoLimits simulation ends, the DLL-subsoutine `GameStop` must close the TcpClient, otherwise the NoLimits simulation hangs.

Because the `tcpClientNLS.Close()` call not only closes the connetcion but also disposes the tcpClient, it is no longer accessible.
So the next time the NoLimits simulation starts and the `DLL-GameStart` routine tries to connect the TcpClient with `tcpClientNLS.Connect("127.0.0.1", 15151)` it throws an exception.
I have tried several different options - so far with no luck.

- Is it possible to create a new TcpClient within a subroutine (e.g.
  `DLL-GameStart`) and access it in another subroutine (e.g.
  `DLL-GameStop`)?
- I can also create a new TcpClient in the
  `DLL-Process_Telemetry` subroutine everytime I read the telemetry data
  from the NoLimits Simulation and close the TcpClient right after
  (100× per sec) in the same `DLL-Process_Telemetry` subroutine. But I
  guess this just consumes a lot of processing time?
- Is there
  another way to close the connection and reuse the TcpClient?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to create a new TcpClient within a subroutine (e.g. DLL-GameStart) and access it in another subroutine (e.g. DLL-GameStop)?

It's not possible to create a *new variable* within a method/subroutine and then access it from the outside,

***BUT*** you can always reinstantiate your global `tcpClientNLS` variable whenever you like, for example in your `GameStart()` method:

```
Dim tcpClientNLS As TcpClient

Public Sub GameStart()
    tcpClientNLS = New TcpClient()
    tcpClientNLS.Connect("127.0.0.1", 15151)
    ...
End Sub
```

> I can also create a new TcpClient in the DLL-Process_Telemetry subroutine everytime I read the telemetry data from the NoLimits Simulation and close the TcpClient right after (100× per sec) in the same DLL-Process_Telemetry subroutine. But I guess this just consumes a lot of processing time?

Doing so can potentially slow things down, yes.

> Is there another way to close the connection and reuse the TcpClient?

You can always reinstantiate it (like shown above) right after the `tcpClientNLS.Close()` call too.

Comment: Thank you so much @Visual Vincent for the edit and the quick answer. Works fine now :) So great to have such supportive people like you and the stackoverflow community!!!

Comment: @value1 : No problem, glad I could help! Good luck with your project!